# How to compare TextFrom UI and Text Which is received from Web Service in KIF 3.1.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kif, kif-framework

I want to comare Text From UI and What I get from WebService Using KIF V3.0. I know how to compare in KIF 1.0 but KIF V3.0 I don't know.

For V1.0

+(id)stepToverifyOutput:(NSString *) expectedLabel accessibility:(NSString *)mylabel

{

```
NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Verify label text for %@",expectedLabel];
return [self stepWithDescription:description executionBlock:^(KIFTestStep *step, NSError **error) {
    UIAccessibilityElement *element = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] accessibilityElementWithLabel:mylabel];

    BOOL isValid;
    UINavigationController *navbar;
    UILabel *lblName;

    if([element isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        isValid=YES;
        lblName = (UILabel *)[UIAccessibilityElement viewContainingAccessibilityElement:element];;
        if ([expectedLabel isEqualToString:lblName.text]) {
            return KIFTestStepResultSuccess;
        }
    }else{
        isValid=NO;
         navbar = (UINavigationController *)[UIAccessibilityElement viewContainingAccessibilityElement:element];;
        if ([expectedLabel isEqualToString:navbar.title]) {
            return KIFTestStepResultSuccess;
        }
    }
    KIFTestCondition(NO, error, @"Failed to compare the label text: expected '%@', actual '%@'", expectedLabel,(isValid)?lblName.text:navbar.title);
}];
```

}

Please do needful for me.I am stuck at this place.

Comment: instead of (lblName.text) pass some hardcoded string and check it. If it works pass this (lblName.text) to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KIF's `[tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:myLabel]` method returns the actual view itself, which you can then use to assert.  So for example:

```
NSString *accessibilityLabel = @"yourLabel";
NSString *expectedValue = @"whateveryouexpect";

UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:accessibilityLabel];
XCTAssert([label.text isEqualToString:expectedValue], @"BADONKADONK");
```

You don't need to run a whole step for it.  This also has the advantage of being much more readable and straight forward: get a label, make sure it's text value is as expected.  If the value isn't found then the test will naturally fail.

Comment: do you know how to check KIF Test Report for V3.1.1 in device?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by KIF test report. Results of kif tests are reported through XCTest.

Comment: I have automated 10 test case in KIF.I wanted to the results of that 10 test case.How i can show the result?I am new to XCTest.If I will get that XCTest file In which app i should open it?

Answer (score 1):

I think i an getting right your question. you are facing the problem to compare to string if this only then you can directly by your custom code like :

if (yourFirstString isEqualTo:YourSecondString)

```
  {
       //Text Matches.
  }
```

else

```
 {
      //Text not matches.
 }
```